# Laravel Lucid mock job

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

Using the great software architecture [Lucid](https://docs.lucidarch.dev) in my application, I need to provide some authorization logic.

I have an [operation](https://docs.lucidarch.dev/operations/) `AuthorizeOperation`, which contain step by step flow with [jobs](https://docs.lucidarch.dev/jobs/) calling.

Schematically the operation content looks like:

- run `GetLocalAuthorizationDataJob`
- ...
- run `GetRemoteAuthorizationDataJob`
- ...
- run `CalculateJob`
- ...

The `GetRemoteAuthorizationDataJob@handle` method finally returns results of remote data source request. Let's assume the results is an array.

The question is **how to mock this results in my unit tests with required data?**

I tried to mock the method `GetRemoteAuthorizationDataJob@handle` as usually:

```
    $this->instance(
        GetRemoteAuthorizationDataJob::class,
        \Mockery::mock(
            GetRemoteAuthorizationDataJob::class,
            function ($mock) {
                $mock->shouldReceive('handle')->andReturn([
                    'key_1' => 'required_value_1',
                     //...
                    'key_n' => 'required_value_n',
                ]);
            }
        )
    );
```

but it did'n help in my case.

Answer (score 2):

The only solution with the current implementation is to partially mock the feature that calls the operation, or partially mock the operation that calls the job.

**Feature Mocking**

This is only recommended in case the operation itself has tests that guarantee its work.

```php
$mFeature = m::mock(CustomFeature::class)->makePartial();
$mFeature->shouldReceive('run')
  ->with(AuthorizeOperation::class, $params)
  ->andReturn($result);
```

**Job Call Mocking**

```php
$mOperation = m::mock(AuthorizeOperation::class)->makePartial();
$mOperation->shouldReceive('run')
  ->with(GetRemoteAuthorizationDataJob::class, $params)
  ->andReturn($result);
```

Partial mocking allows for non-mocked methods to actually execute with the results that's been returned in the mocked method calls, though parameters in `with()` must match exactly what is being passed to `$this->run` in the dispatching class.

---

Internally we've been discussing a better way than this that would allow your approach to work (replacing unit instances in the container), will keep you posted as soon as this is out!

---

**Update**

There is now a much easier way to mock units! See the [Testing docs](https://docs.lucidarch.dev/testing/) for granular details.

In summary, you may use the `Unit::mock($args)` method on any unit (feature, job, operation) in tests to mock then and return what's expected.

```php
GetUserByIDJob::mock(['id' => $id])->shouldReturn($user);
```